# Customize sticky behaviour of Cart Summary: Magento 2

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, magento-2.1

I have a custom theme based on the Luma theme. And in this custom theme, I have made the header sticky.

By default, the Cart Summary is sticky as well. Now because my header is sticky as well, both of them are overlapped. This is how it looks.

[image: Sticky Header and Cart summary]
How can I customize (or remove) this behaviour?

Can someone please point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your site url ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a live site, it is only in my local system.

Comment: Having this same issue :(

Comment: @Volvox, I've added my solution below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this. The sticky behavior of the cart summary is due to the code in the file `magento_root/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js`.

```
$('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {
    container: '#maincontent'
});
```

To remove this functionality, I copied the file `theme.js` to my theme `magento_root/app/design/frontend/customvendor/customtheme/web/js/theme.js` and commented out the above piece of code, and removed the `magento_root/pub/static/frontend` files.

Hope it is helpful to someone else.

> theme.js is located under the /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js

and make replica of this file under your theme's theme module directory

> app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js

Answer (score 3):

There is a option in the _stick function that maybe wasn't available when the previous comment was added.  You can add spacing to the top of the scrolling container using the spacingTop option as follows:

```
$('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {
container: '#maincontent',
spacingTop: 150 //height of sticky header in px
});
```

There is also an option to delay scrolling until the element has gone out of view called "stickAfter"

See  'lib/web/mage/sticky.js'

theme.js has also now been relocated to:

> magento_root/app/design/frontend/customvendor/customtheme/Magento_Theme/js/theme.js

Comment: This is the best answer for the current version (Magento 2.2.6) 2018/11/29

Answer (score 1):

You can also customize the sticky behaviour so that it's not overlapped anymore.
You need to copy the 'lib/web/mage/sticky.js' to 'app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/mage/sticky.js' and add the fixed header height to the offset in the method _stick:

```
/**
     * float Block on windowScroll
     * @private
     */
    _stick: function() {
        var offset,
            isStatic;

        isStatic = this.element.css('position') === 'static';

        if( !isStatic && this.element.is(':visible') ) {
            var fixedHeaderHeight = parseFloat($('.page-wrapper').css('padding-top')) + 20;
            offset = $(document).scrollTop() - this.parentOffset + fixedHeaderHeight;

            offset = Math.max( 0, Math.min( offset, this.maxOffset) );

            this.element.css( 'top', offset);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That definitely solves the fixed header issue. But I also have a large footer because of which the cart summary goes inside the footer. Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I just finished dealing with the same problem. In my case, I wanted to render the cart summary widget in another page and being sticky just ruins everything.

I simply ran the following line of code when my javascript component loads and it removes the sticky behavior.

`$('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {});`