# Remove sticky behaviour of cart summary in Magento 2.2

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, cart, magento2.2.6

i need to disable sticky behaviour from the cart summary block in checkout cart page, but can't figure out how to do it.

I tried overriding js file

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js

into

> app/design/frontend/MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js

and commenting out sticky call:

```
 /* $('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {
    container: '#maincontent'
  }); */
```

as is suggested in [Customize sticky behaviour of Cart Summary: Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131638/customize-sticky-behaviour-of-cart-summary-magento-2), without success.

I'm using `Magento 2.2.6`

Thanks in advance,

Antonio.

Comment: Please refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131638/customize-sticky-behaviour-of-cart-summary-magento-2

Answer (score 3):

**Fastest and rude solution:**

On your custom theme CSS file add this:

```
.cart-summary {
   position: unset !important;
}
```

I found this solution as I'm not using theme.js to custom my theme and worked fine for me on Magento 2.3...

*Maybe not the best practice but works fine for most situations.*

Comment: Works perfectly +1.

Answer (score 0):

Also remove this js code from your pub folder.
It may be

***pub/static/frontend/MyVendor/MyTheme/js/theme.js***

I just finished dealing with the same problem. In my case, I wanted to render the cart summary widget in another page and being sticky just ruins everything.

I simply ran the following line of code when my javascript component loads and it removes the sticky behavior.

```
$('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {});
```