# How to make order summary block in checkout as sticky in magento 2.3.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, order-summary, sticky-menu

[image]

I want to make that order summary as sticky. How to do that?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136786/85907

Comment: There is no theme.js in that path in Magento 2.3.3. There is only navigation-menu.js file in that path.

Comment: Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can able to make order summaries like sticky ones using simple custom CSS.

I have added the following CSS in my class.

.opc-sidebar.opc-summary-wrapper {
margin: 0px 0 0px;
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}

It works fine for me on both checkout and payment pages.